# Prevent universal links from opening in `WKWebView`/`UIWebView`

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

When user tap on a universal link in `WKWebView`, the corresponding app will be opened (if installed).

This is described in [Apple Search Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

> If you instantiate a SFSafariViewController, WKWebView, or UIWebView object to handle a universal link, iOS opens your website in Safari instead of opening your app. However, if the user taps a universal link from within an embedded SFSafariViewController, WKWebView, or UIWebView object, iOS opens your app.

In my app, I have a `WKWebView`, but I don't want the user to go out of my app. I want to handle the link within my `WKWebView`.

How do I prevent universal link from opening? Or can I know if a URL could be handle by other apps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

sourcecode for WebKit:

`static const WKNavigationActionPolicy WK_API_AVAILABLE(macosx(10.11), ios(9.0)) _WKNavigationActionPolicyAllowWithoutTryingAppLink = (WKNavigationActionPolicy)(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow + 2);`

if you are using `WKWebView`, just use `WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow` + 2 instead of `WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow`

Comment: is this considered a private API call though? That would mean using this could lead to immediate rejection from the App Store, right?

Comment: Strongly recommend against using `magic numbers` — will likely cause issues in future iOS versions

Comment: Strongly recommend against using `magic numbers` — will likely cause issues in future iOS versions

Comment: It's private value https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/995f6b1595611c934e742a4f3a9af2e678bc6b8d/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKNavigationDelegatePrivate.h#L61

Comment: Its Private API, should not use.

Answer (score 6):

Base on @none 's answer, here is an example for Swift 4

I've tested it and it does work!

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy(rawValue: WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow.rawValue + 2)!)
}
```

Comment: does not work for iOS 11 anymore. additionally, it's private API.

Answer (score 2):

+[LSAppLink openWithURL:completionHandler:]
this is how universal link open corresponding app.
you can exchange its implementations with yourself method
but be carefule,this is private API.

you can check LSAppLink head file [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/LSAppLink.h)

Comment: reference to doc is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy(rawValue: WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow.rawValue + 2)!)
}
```