# How to prevent universal link in `UIWebView`

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios-universal-links

How to prevent universal link in `UIWebView`,`WKWebView`i know how to prevent,but `UIWebView` can prevent universal link?

Comment: for wkwebview how you prevent ?

Comment: You can get help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450586/prevent-universal-links-from-opening-in-wkwebview-uiwebview?rq=1