# Swift 5 Disable redirection to other apps inside WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

First of all... My other question got marked as a *duplicate* even though the question suggested was the exact opposite, so:

Inside my `webView` I **do not** want to be redirected to other apps. `WKWebView` should never redirect to other Apps. Instead it should just open the `url`.

This is my `webView`:

```
lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return webView
}()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable WKWebView for opening links to redirect to apps installed on my iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086605/disable-wkwebview-for-opening-links-to-redirect-to-apps-installed-on-my-iphone)

Comment: @WitekBobrowski no... as mentioned in the comments of this question the suggested answer is not working on the latest iOS versions

Comment: What do you mean by other apps? Other hosts outside of the one you provide to WKWebView?

Comment: @LucaSfragara I don't my `webView` to redirect to other apps I have on my phone. For example: If I serach for "Zalando" in my `webView` and tap on the first link, I get redirected to my Zalando App. I do not want that! It should simply open the URL inside my `webView`

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about wanting to prevent universal links from opening other apps from your web view. I don't think it's possible unless you use private API, as shown in some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450586/prevent-universal-links-from-opening-in-wkwebview-uiwebview).

Comment: @Tyler I dont see a working function for Swift 5 there or am I wrong ?